# Copy cells from sheet A in sheet B based on information in cell x in sheet A

Tags: google-sheets

In Sheet A I have this information:

**Name A | Name B | Name C |** Field 1 | Field 2 | *Field 3*

For each row there would be only one name (either in column Name A, Name B or Name C)

If Field 3 is different than 0, I want to display in sheet B:

**Name** | Field 1 | Field 2 | *Field 3*

In name it should be a value from either Name A, Name B or Name C column (knowing that the value will be in one and only one of these three columns randomly)

How can I do this ?

Comment: You'll need to learn some JavaScript, and use it in Apps Script.  In order to answer your question, the answer would need to be like a tutorial, or a part of a chapter in a book on how to do something.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula in sheet B:

```
=QUERY(
  {ARRAYFORMULA(
    SUBSTITUTE(
      trim(
        transpose(
          query(transpose('Sheet A'!A2:C),,COLUMNS('Sheet A'!A2:C))
        )
     ),"","")
   ),'Sheet A'!D2:F},
 "select * where Col4 <> 0")
```

I ussumed that data looks like this:

[image]

The rasult will show like this:

[image]

Formula was pasted into call A2 in my example.